# How do I determine rows in a vector/list which contain more than one entry?

Tags: r, list, vector, row

[Screenshot of list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyZHJ.png)

I have a list of areas taken from a spatialpolygonsdataframe which now has mostly entries with one element. However, a few of them contain 2 or sometimes 3 areas per row (each row is a polygon, those other areas are usually holes for reference). The list looks similar to this:

```
arealist =

Name     Type        Value
arealist list[120]   List of length 120
[[1]]    double[1]   0.0007
[[2]]    double[1]   0.00043
[[3]]    double[1]   0.0006
[[4]]    double[1]   0.0002
[[5]]    double[1]   0.00012  0.0023
[[6]]    double[1]   0.0007
```

As you can see, row 5 has 2 areas listed, and the rest have one area listed. I tried the following:

```
arealist[length>1]

"Error in length > 1 : 
  comparison (6) is possible only for atomic and list types"
```

But the header of my file arealist says 'list [120]' which is a list of 120 elements. I went through and saw if it was considered a matrix or vector and it says vector or matrix:

```
is.matrix(arealist)
# [1] FALSE
is.vector(arealist)
# [1] TRUE
```

I also tried:

```
grep('[length(arealist)>1]',arealist)
```

Which just listed row indices 1 through 120.

```
which(length(arealist[[1:NROW(arealist)]])>1)

# Error in arealist[[1:NROW(arealist)]] : 
#   recursive indexing failed at level 2

which(length(arealist[[1:120]])>1)
# Error in arealist[[1:120]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2

which(length(arealist[[1:120,]])>1)    
# Error in arealist[[1:120, ]] : incorrect number of subscripts

which(length(arealist[[1]])>1)
# integer(0)

which(length(arealist[[112]])>1)
# [1] 1
```

In my actual arealist list there are 4 instances where there are multiple areas so both 0 and 1 aren't correct. Any thoughts? Thank you

PS, this is how I have gotten a list of areas in the polygon previously:

> arealist <- sapply(slot(poly, "polygons"), function(x) sapply(slot(x, "Polygons"), slot, "area"))
>
> flatarea <- unlist(arealist, use.names=FALSE) #flatten list
>
> maxareatf <-  flatarea > 0.02 #gives True/false answer only
>
> maxareaidx <- which(maxareatf==TRUE) #which have areas greater than threshold
>
> maxareaidx <- as.numeric(maxareaidx) #make numeric class
>
> maxareasub = subset(flatarea, flatarea[] > 0.02) #subset out those with larger areas than thresh
>
> maxarea = data.frame(maxareaidx, maxareasub) #make matrix of indexes and areas greater than thresh

The output has area slots which can contain more than one area though, so same issue.

Comment: You should share `dput(arealist)`. It's unclear with what you posted what exactly is the structure of the object you are interacting with.

Comment: How about `arealist[lengths(arealist) > 1]`

Comment: > dput(arealist)
list(0.000722222222222215, 0.00022222222222222, 3.33333333333319e-05, 
    2.22222222222227e-05, 0.000322222222222221, 1.11111111111111e-05, 
    2.22222222222221e-05, 1.11111111111111e-05, etc)

Comment: So are you looking for a script that will identify which rows have two or more values?

Comment: @RichScriven so this works except I need to retain the indicies also. Is there a way to keep the indicies maybe? Thank you!

Comment: @BenG yes, and keep the info of which row its from (the index of those rows)

Comment: I am curious, why pull these out from a list from a spatial polygon in the first place? Is it not possible to pull the area values directly from the @data portion of the spdf object?

Comment: @elmuertefurioso yes but this is for something in particular. I already have some code which subsets which areas are for which polygon but have the same issue for needing to find which indices contain multiple area entries.